# I can't find the corresponding file or interface in "github"，Can you tell me what to do next?

Tags: dapps

[image]

I can't find the corresponding file or interface in "github"，Can you tell me what to do next?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.